# Form validation without submission

Tags: jquery

I am using .NET MVC 3, with DataAnnotations for client side field validation. Everything works fine on form submission, however, the form is long, and we're using 'Next' buttons to show and hide divs for sections prior to posting.

I'd like to validate the form and then change divs without form submission. I have tried different variations of the following, but the form is always being submitted.

```
$('#btnNext').click(function (e) {
    if ($('form').valid()) {
        $('#div1').hide();
        $('#div2').show();
        return false;   
    }
    //return false;
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: And, will the form be valid before it's filled out completely?

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault to stop the form being submitted:

```
$('#btnNext').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('form').valid()) {
        $('#div1').hide();
        $('#div2').show();
        return false;   
    }
    //return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a line `e.preventDefault();` to keep the event behaving normally.

```
$('#btnNext').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('form').valid()) {
        $('#div1').hide();
        $('#div2').show();
        return false;   
    }
    //return false;
});
```